# How to execute query with empty fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL Query:

```
SELECT documents.*, t_rights.rights, documents_list.docs
FROM documents 
INNER JOIN t_rights on t_rights.num=documents.type_right 
INNER JOIN documents_list on documents_list.num=documents.document1 
WHERE code_document=1 or code_document=1
```

In case if i have fields `documents.document1` and `documents.document1` with some value all works fine. But if this field empty i get empty query result.
Its possible make query like this with empty fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think you will need to replace your `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include rows even when there is not a match:

```
SELECT documents.*, t_rights.rights, documents_list.docs
    FROM documents 
    INNER JOIN t_rights on t_rights.num = documents.type_right 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN documents_list on
        documents_list.num = documents.document1 
    WHERE code_document=1
```

Now you will get rows from documents even if they don't match anything in `documents_list`.  However, maybe you want to include *only* the non-matching documents that have the `document1`  field empty.  In which case, you would need a little more:

```
SELECT documents.*, t_rights.rights, documents_list.docs
    FROM documents 
    INNER JOIN t_rights on t_rights.num = documents.type_right 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN documents_list on
        documents_list.num = documents.document1 
    WHERE code_document = 1 and (
        documents_list.num is not null or
        documents.document1 is null
    )
```

This only returns documents that match the `document_list`, *except* those cases in which `document1` is null (I assumed that by "empty" you meant null; if not, put your own condition there).